# Python function object on Map function going weird. (Spark)

Tags: dictionary, function-pointers, pyspark, rdd

I have a dictionary that maps a key to a function object. Then, using Spark 1.4.1 (Spark may not even be relevant for this question), I try to map each object in the RDD using a function object retrieved from the dictionary (acts as look-up table). e.g. a small snippet of my code:

```
fnCall = groupFnList[0].fn
pagesRDD = pagesRDD.map(lambda x: [x, fnCall(x[0])]).map(shapeToTuple)
```

Now, it has fetched from a namedtuple the function object. Which I temporarily 'store' (c.q. pointing to fn obj) in FnCall. Then, using the map operations I want the x[0] element of each tuple to be processed using that function. 
All works fine and good in that there indeed IS a fn object, but it behaves in a weird way.
Each time I call an action method on the RDD, even without having used a fn obj in between, the RDD values have changed! To visualize this I have created dummy functions for the fn objects that just output a random integer. After calling the fn obj on the RDD, I can inspect it with .take() or .first() and get the following:

```
pagesRDD.first()
>>> [(u'myPDF1.pdf', u'34', u'930', u'30')]
pagesRDD.first()
>>> [(u'myPDF1.pdf', u'23', u'472', u'11')]
pagesRDD.first()
>>> [(u'myPDF1.pdf', u'4', u'69', u'25')]
```

So it seems to me that the RDD's elements have the functions bound to them in some way, and each time I do an action operation (like .first(), very simple) it 'updates' the RDD's contents. 
I don't want this to happen! I just want the function to process the RDD ONLY when I call it with a map operation. How can I 'unbind' this function after the map operation?

Any ideas?
Thanks!

**####### UPDATE:**

So apparently rewriting my code to call it like `pagesRDD.map(fnCall)` should do the trick, but why should this even matter? If I call

```
rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: (x,1))
rdd.first()
>>> # some output
rdd.first()
>>> # same output as before!
```

So in this case, using a lambda function it would not get bound to the rdd and would not be called each time I do a .take()-like action. So why is that the case when I use a fn object INSIDE the lambda? Logically it just does not make sense to me. Any explanation on this?

Comment: Could explain what you mean when you say _each time I call an action method on the RDD, even without having used a fn obj in between, the RDD values have changed_ in other context than a function generating random numbers? What exactly is going on in your functions?

Answer (score 0):

If you redefine your functions that their parameter is an iterable. Your code should look like this.

```
pagesRDD = pagesRDD.map(fnCall).map(shapeToTuple)
```